# IdentationError in python when using RBF

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

```
 #1-d interpolation  

        import numpy as np  
        from scipy import interpolate  
        import pylab as py  
        import pandas as pd  

        #Read the Dataset from Excel File  
        def func(x1):  
            return x1*np.exp(-5.0*x1**2)  
        dataset=pd.read_excel('Messwerte_FIBRE1.xlsx')  
        dataset=dataset.drop([0])  
        index=[1]    
        index2=[9]  
        x=dataset.iloc[:, index]    
        y=dataset.iloc[:, index2]  
        x1=np.array(x,dtype=float)  
        y1=np.array(y,dtype=float)  
        fvals=func(x1)   
        xnew=np.linespace(430,490,800)   
        for kind in ['multiquadric','inverse multiquadric','gaussian',  
                     'linear','cubic','quintic','thin-plate']:  
        newfunc=interpolate.Rbf(x1,fvals,function=kind)    
        fnew=newfunc(xnew)
```

I am getting an error:
IndentationError: expected an indented block**
Can any1 help me in fixation? I am trying to read variables from excel file and using RBF interpolation technique for prediction estimation
My excel file looks like this,please click on it

[Messwerte_FIBRE1.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kG9V.png)

Answer (score 1):

Right here the for loop expects code to be in the block.

```
xnew=np.linespace(430,490,800)   
for kind in ['multiquadric','inverse multiquadric','gaussian',  
             'linear','cubic','quintic','thin-plate']: 
    #SOMETHING WOULD GO HERE    
newfunc=interpolate.Rbf(x1,fvals,function=kind)    
fnew=newfunc(xnew)
```